# Is disappearing after going to another activity but showing uploading to server Glide and volley

Tags: android, image, sharedpreferences, android-imageview, android-glide

I have created two functionality for photo uploading in my app. The first one is for capture image and the second one is for pick image from gallery. Now I have a photo API as URL. By using this API I have to upload the image at first to server and from server it will be available throught the app. Now I can successfully uploaded the picture in server and in the server side shows the picture. But in the imageview of app does not show that image. Whenever I go to another activity and then come back to image activity the imageview is empty. I have used shared preference to keep the image at image view, but that does not work.

Here is my code for photo activity

```
    public class ViewProfileFragment extends Fragment implements
        View.OnClickListener{
    private static final int CODE_GALLERY_REQUEST =999 ;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    private ImageView image;

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private String userChoosenTask;
    Bitmap bm;

    private String UPLOAD_URL = Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_profile,
                container, false);
        .........
        image=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        saveData();
        return rootView;
    }
    public void saveData(){
        Log.d( "----ViewProfile-Email", "mEmail" );
        GlobalClass globalClass = new GlobalClass();
        String mEmail = globalClass.getEmail_info();
        Realm profileRealm;
        profileRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<MyColleagueModel> results =
                profileRealm.where(MyColleagueModel.class).equalTo("mail",
                        mEmail).findAll();
        //fetching the data
        results.load();
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            ......
            SharedPreferences preferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);
            if (mImageUri != null) {
                image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
            } else {
                Glide.with( this )
                        .load(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL+mail)
                        .thumbnail(0.5f)
                        .override(200,200)
                        .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into( image);
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[]
            permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode==CODE_GALLERY_REQUEST){
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                galleryIntent();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"You
                        don't have permission to access gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        if(requestCode==MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                cameraIntent();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"You
                        don't have permission to access gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult( requestCode, permissions,grantResults );
    }
    public void showDialog(){
//Create a new builder and get the layout.
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
                AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        .....
            }
        });
        alertListView.setOnItemClickListener(new

       AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                 int position, long id) {
// ListViekw Clicked item index
             if (position == 0) {
                 userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                 alert.dismiss();

                 if(isPermissionGrantedCamera()) {

                  cameraIntent();
                                                  }
                  }
                else if (position == 1){

                 userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";

                 alert.dismiss();

                 if(isPermissionGrantedGallery()) {

                  galleryIntent();
                                     }
                  }
              }
         });
    }

      public boolean isPermissionGrantedGallery() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if
                 (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(), new
                        String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon
            installation
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
    public boolean isPermissionGrantedCamera() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if
                    (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(), new
                        String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon
            installation
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select
                File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }
    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if
                (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            File cameraFolder;
            if
                    (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                cameraFolder = new
                        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image/");
            } else {
                cameraFolder = getActivity().getCacheDir();
            }
            if (!cameraFolder.exists()) {
                cameraFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            String imageFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";File photoFile = new File(cameraFolder + imageFileName);
            currentPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && data!=null){
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            }
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA ) {
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentPhotoPath)) {
                    try {
                        galleryAddPic();
                        onCaptureImageResult();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
    private void onCaptureImageResult() {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromPath(currentPhotoPath, 200, 200);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        compressBitMap(bitmap);
    }
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            currentPhotoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            currentPhotoPath = uri.getPath();
        }// Saves image URI as string to Default Shared Preferences

    SharedPreferences preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(uri));
    editor.commit();

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
    compressBitMap(bm);
    }
    private void compressBitMap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ImageConversion imageConversion = new ImageConversion();
        byte[] bytesArray;
        int maxSize = 10 * 1024;
        int imageMaxQuality = 50;
        int imageMinQuality = 5;
        bytesArray = imageConversion.convertBitmapToByteArray(bitmap,
                imageMaxQuality, imageMinQuality, maxSize);
        File destination = new
                File(getContext().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytesArray);
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentPhotoPath = destination.getPath();
        uploadImage(bytesArray);
    }

    private void uploadImage(final byte[] bytesArray){
       .....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use

```
image.setImageURI(uri);
image.invalidate();
```

Please use this code below instead of that :

```
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I just tried with your code, but still the same result, whenever i go to another activity the image dissaperas

Comment: are you sure  you are getting right image url ? Please try to hit it on browser see image appears or not

Comment: I want to show the image url with glide. I set a system out in gllide  System.out.println(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL+mail); it is showing 0, but when I only run the code with else portion insteade of if I can see the image url

Comment: you will need image url  from server side after image uploaded to server. you can not use uri to set image after coming back to another activity because it recreate all view and your imageview will not able to set your past uri

Comment: could you please explain how can I do that, Shall I use image url in sharedpreferance. inthat case, how can i Modif ythe code. I ma very new in handling this situation, could you please explain a bit more